# How to detect the exact type of a document in java

Tags: java

how to detect the exact type of documents in java.Actually I will be getting lots of documents like articles,manuals and guides and so on in run time and I need to identify their actual type using java. The documents can be PDF,HTML,DOC,XML etc. I will not have even the extension of the documents. See I will be getting the documents from db..In case of PDFs only I will have the extension but in case of HTMLs and others I will not have the extension. Actually after getting the content only I will have to judge that which kind of content it is and then I will implement my business logic...Please help me.

Comment: Why will you not have the extension/content-type?  How are the files getting to you?

Comment: see I will be getting the documents from db..In case of PDFs only I will have the extension but in case of HTMLs and others I will not have the extension. Actually after getting the content only I will have to judge that which kind of content it is...

Comment: best practice is to capture the mime-type *along with* the data.  You should have two columns, one for the mime-type, and one for the data.

Comment: @kirk, yeah Kirk I should have done that only but I will not have the MIME type in any in any column, Actually after getting the content I will have to guess the correct mime-type on the fly. Suppose I will get a content as String like "<HTML><BODY><H3>WELCOME KIRK WOLL</H3></BODY></HTML>". I will have to detect the mime-type of this document text/html and then I will have to open it in a shadow box with a proper icon for the detected mime-type. I hope u will get my point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apache Tika has facilities to detect MIME types of files:

http://tika.apache.org/

It is pretty heavy-weight, however, as it does a lot more than just MIME type detection.

Answer (score 1):

Give [FITS](http://code.google.com/p/fits/wiki/tools) a try, it encapsulates the following  tools for identifying, validating, and extracting technical metadata:

1. Jhove
2. Exiftool
3. National Library of New Zealand Metadata Extractor (NLNZ)
4. File Utility
5. DROID
6. FFIdent
7. FileInfo
8. XmlMetadata